# Consultar se SLUG já existe

Tags: php, mysql

Gostaria de saber como eu faço pra consultar se um SLUG já existe no banco de dados e, caso exista, como incrementar +1 ao fim da string, ficando:

```
site.com/artigo/titulo-de-teste1    
site.com/artigo/titulo-de-teste2    
site.com/artigo/titulo-de-teste3
```

Tentei utilizando SELECT:

```
$slug = $_POST["slug"];
 $slug = slug($titulo, '-');
 $consulta = mysqli_query($conecta, "SELECT * FROM conteudo WHERE slug LIKE '$slug%'"); 

$listaSlugs = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta);
 if($slug == $linha && $listaSlugs >0){ 
echo 'encontrou slug'; 
// aqui eu quero fazer com que $slug fique com +1 caso haja algum identico no banco 
// ex: se encontrar titulo-teste, fique titulo-teste1, titulo-teste2 } 
else { // continua o codigo.. com INSERT}
```

Li algo sobre criar o campo como *unique* e Tentei de diversas formas, mas não consegui, porque não sei como deve ser o tipo do campo (VARCHAR, TEXT, etc..)

Comment: mostre como tentou fazer o select

Comment: $slug = $_POST["slug"];
    $slug = slug($titulo, '-');
 
$consulta = mysqli_query($conecta, "SELECT * FROM conteudo WHERE slug LIKE '$slug%'");
$listaSlugs = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta);
 
if($slug == $linha && $listaSlugs >0){
echo 'encontrou slug';
// aqui eu quero fazer com que $slug fique com +1 caso haja algum identico no banco
// ex: se encontrar titulo-teste, fique titulo-teste1, titulo-teste2
}
else
{
// continua o codigo

Comment: coloca isso na pergunta.. edite a pergunta..

Comment: Pronto Daniel Omine!

Comment: Comecei a fazer e estava quase postando uma resposta. Mas então percebi que a coisa não é tão simples assim. se tiver paciência, outro dia postarei algo mais conciso. Pensei que fosse simples, mas não é tão simples assim, dentro das condições que apresentou.  Fiz algo com uma instrução SQL parecida com a resposta do Lucas, ao invés do `LIKE` troquei por `=`, mas é justamente isso que percebi que é um erro pois dessa forma nunca encontrará um incremento existente. É justamente essa a parte mais complexa.

Comment: Eu consegui fazer uma comparação da seguinte forma:
if($slug == 'teste') {
echo "O slug $slug já existe"; 
} else {
//continua o código..
}

O verdadeiro problema foi quando eu tentei comparar com os slugs j á existentes no banco de dados..

Comment: Exato.. hehe isso vai dar um trampo e requer tempo. Não disponho desse tempo agora, mas gostei do desafio. Se nenhuma outra pessoa postar antes, vou tentar postar alguma solução. Mas não fique esperando que eu venha entregar a resposta pronta pois não posso comprometer e prometer nada. Pensei em algo como, verificar a data de cadastro. A lógica seria também filtrar pela data do mais recente. Se não possui data de cadastro ou algum outro campo onde podemos verificar que é o registro mais novo, vai complicar.

Comment: Não é possível só consultar se o valor da string $slug já existe na coluna slug em meu banco de dados?
Postei o código no pastebin, dê uma olhada se puder.
http://pastebin.com/vdr3mtzw

Comment: não rola.. a coisa é complexa. Você pode reduzir a complexidade de uma  solução adicionando um campo que identifique a "idade" do registro. A lógica é conseguir identificar qual o registro mais recente. Sugiro um campo id numérico de auto incremento ou um campo de data (date_created). Particularmente usaria data.  Mãos na massa! Procure resolver o seu trabalho.

Comment: Eu pensei que fosse a mesma coisa de um sistema de cadastro, que se o usuario já existir ele não armazena.. no meu caso eu só quero, caso exista, incremente um numero no final.

Comment: Incrementar um número numa primeira ocorrência é simples. O problema é se precisar de um segundo incremento. Exemplo de slug "slug-teste". Suponha que já exista, então o novo ficaria como "slug-teste1". Agora suponha que novamente tente cadastrar "slug-teste". Como vai conseguir saber se já não existe o "slug-teste1"? E a coisa vai embora, "slug-teste2", "slug-teste100", "slug-teste2000".. Sacou? O modelo de negócio de um cadastro de usuário é bem diferente da lógica do negócio que vc quer. Talvez precise mudar a lógica do negócio ou fazer o que sugeri ou encontrar alguma outra solução. Enfim.

Comment: Tem alguma ideia diferente do incremento em cada slug?
Se houver algo que me facilite, algum termo ao final, não sei, algo do tipo.. estou aberto a sugestões!

Comment: em primeiro lugar, não gosto da ideia de incremento e tampouco da técnica de usar o slung como identificador de um registro. Poderia usar Id numérico único. Assim, eliminaria esse problema com slung. Com ID numérico como identificador, as URLs teriam que ficar como `site.com/artigo/1/titulo-de-teste`. Quando houver um nome exatamente igual a um existente, não conflitaria a URL devido ao ID: `site.com/artigo/2/titulo-de-teste`

Comment: outra técnica muito utilizada é diferenciar as URLs pela data de cadastro. Seria algo assim `site.com/artigo/20151207/titulo-de-teste`. Quando surgir um titulo igual, porém em dia diferente , ficaria assim `site.com/artigo/20160201/titulo-de-teste`. Sacou? A lógica nisso é que dificilmente será cadastrado um mesmo titulo no mesmo dia. Mas isso depende muito do seu modelo de negócios.  Por fim, há N soluções. Aqui nos comentários forneci diversas dicas e acho que é o suficiente para vc se virar. Afinal isso é o seu trabalho.

Comment: De qualquer forma, obrigado por ajudar.
As chances de ocorrer uma duplicação de slug serão mínimas. Porém, é sempre bom estar preparado e por isso decidi postar a dúvida, só não imaginei que fosse tão complexa.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente, para manter a consistência do banco de dados, você poderia adicionar a restrinção UNIQUE para a coluna 'tabela.slug', dessa forma seria impossível haver dois slugs iguais nesta tabela. Agora o outra solução é verificar se o slug a ser inserido já existe, para evitar que uma exceção seja disparada. No momento lembro de duas:

1 - Selecionar a primeira slug na tabela que corresponda com a slug esta tentando inserir:

```
SELECT slug FROM table WHERE slug = $slug LIMIT 1
```

Se o resultado por vazio, significa que você pode inserir a slug.

2 - Adicionar um bloco try-catch para capturar a exceção caso ela ocorra. Se ocorrer, você retornará um aviso ao usuário de que o título já existe e que ele deve altera-lo.

Uma dica: No exemplo que citou na pergunda você adicionou a variável $slug diretamente na query, o pode ocasionar em uma vulnerabilidade de SQL Injection, portanto, passe a utilizar Prepared Statements para evitar esse problema, pelo menos nos casos mais comuns, nível 1 e 2.

@update

Primeiramente vamos começar convertendo todas as iniciais de cada palavra do título para maiúscula, por padronização, já que o usuário pode digitar tudo minísculo. Uma função para isso seria:

```
function title($str)
{
    return mb_convert_case($str, MB_CASE_TITLE, 'UTF-8');
}
```

Usuário informa o título "aprenda a divulgar sua empresa nas redes sociais".
O retorno da função será "Aprenda A Divulgar Sua Empresa Nas Redes Sociais".

Para o slug, podemos utilizar a seguinte função:

function slug($title, $separator = '-')
{
        $title = toAscii($title);

```
    $flip = $separator == '-' ? '_' : '-';

    $title = preg_replace('!['.preg_quote($flip).']+!u', $separator, $title);

    $title = preg_replace('![^'.preg_quote($separator).'\pL\pN\s]+!u', '', mb_strtolower($title));

    $title = preg_replace('!['.preg_quote($separator).'\s]+!u', $separator, $title);

    return trim($title, $separator);
```

}

Passando o título para a função slug, obteremos a seguinte string:

"aprenda-a-divulgar-sua-empresa-nas-redes-sociais"

O arquivo completo das funções necessárias pode ser encontrado [aqui](https://ghostbin.com/paste/559wg) e elas foram retiradas [daqui](https://github.com/danielstjules/Stringy). Apenas trasformei o paradigma, de orientado a objetos para procedural, que é o que está utilizando, pelo menos é o que penso.

Agora precisamos saber quantos resultados para esse slug existe na tabela X do banco de dados Y, referente a coluna slug.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM tabela WHERE slug LIKE '%aprenda-a-divulgar-sua-empresa-nas-redes-sociais%'
```

Com esse número em mãos, podemos fazer alterar o slug a ser inserido na tabela:

```
$slug = $slug . '-' . $num;
```

"aprenda-a-divulgar-sua-empresa-nas-redes-sociais-1"

Daí fazemos a inserção no banco de dados.

Uma outra maneira, bem mais adotada, é adicionar um número baseado na data e tempo ou outra numeração que garanta a unicidade do slug.

Ex:

```
$slug = strrev(date('dmYHis')).$slug;
```

Também tornar único na tabela a combinação do slug com data de criação do registro, desse modo slugs iguais seriam permitidos. E quanto a URL, o que faço para diferencia-las?

www.mysite.com/posts/{slug}/{id}

www.mysite.com/posts/aprenda-a-divulgar-sua-empresa-nas-redes-sociais/1547
www.mysite.com/posts/aprenda-a-divulgar-sua-empresa-nas-redes-sociais/1550

olhardigital.uol.com.br/noticia/o-facebook-pretende-livrar-seu-feed-de-noticias-de-virais-que-voce-nao-quer-ver/53511

ou

www.mysite.com/posts/{id}-{slug}

www.mysite.com/posts/1547-aprenda-a-divulgar-sua-empresa-nas-redes-sociais
www.mysite.com/posts/1550-aprenda-a-divulgar-sua-empresa-nas-redes-sociais

Nesse último caso você precisaria de uma função para separar o slug da id, utilizando o id para resgatar os dados no banco de dados.

Comment: Desculpe a ignorância, mas não sei se reparou que eu pedi ajuda para converter o campo SLUG(TEXT) para UNIQUE, pois quando tento sempre dá erro..

Comment: Desculpe-me também, respondi sem compreender o que precisava. Se o que precisa é à respeito da geração de slug a partir da quantidade de tuplas que possuem a mesma substring na tabela, então editarei a minha resposta. Ex: um usuário cadastra um post com o titulo "Formas de Ampliar Seu Negócio Online" (o slug seria "formas-de-ampliar-seu-negocio-online"), e depois de um tempo, o mesmo ou outro usuário decidem criar um post com o mesmo título, o que resultaria no slug "formas-de-ampliar-seu-negocio-online-1". Correto?

Comment: Perfeitamente correto!
Porém, já não faço mais ideia de como transformar o campo slug(text) em UNIQUE, muito menos de como saber se a slug já existe na coluna SLUG do meu banco de dados.
Tem alguma forma de entrar em contato?

Comment: Se precisar de ajuda nesse problema: lcdss@live.com.